# What is the meaning of reset_states() and update_state() in tf.keras metrics?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, metrics

I am checking very simple metrics objects in `tensorflow.keras` such as [BinaryAccuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/BinaryAccuracy) or [AUC](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC). They all have `reset_states()` and `update_state()` arguments, but I found their documentation insufficient and unclear.

Can you explain what they mean?

Answer (score 7):

`update_state` measures the metrics (mean, auc, accuracy), and stores them in the object, so it can later be retrieved with `result`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mean_object = tf.metrics.Mean()

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for ix, val in enumerate(values):
    mean_object.update_state(val)
    print(mean_object.result().numpy(), 'is the mean of', values[:ix+1])
```

```
1.0 is the mean of [1]
1.5 is the mean of [1, 2]
2.0 is the mean of [1, 2, 3]
2.5 is the mean of [1, 2, 3, 4]
3.0 is the mean of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`reset_states` resets the metric to zero:

```
mean_object.reset_states()
mean_object.result().numpy()
```

```
0.0
```

I'm not sure I made it more clear than the documentation, it's pretty well explained in my opinion.

Calling the object, e.g., `mean_object([1, 2, 3, 4])` will update the metric, *and* return the `result`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

mean_object = tf.metrics.Mean()

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(mean_object.result())
returned_mean = mean_object(values)
print(mean_object.result())
print(returned_mean)
```

```
tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(3.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(3.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What is not clear is why use `update_state()` instead of simply `accuracy_object(x, y)`. This can be done in `tf.keras`. Is it the same, or a different thing? And if so, why?

Comment: you mean using `mean_object.update_state(a, b)` rather than just calling the `mean_object(a, b)`? See edit

Comment: Yes, that is my question

Comment: I answered that at the bottom

Comment: @Leevo It may worth noting that when iterating over batches, one batch is available at a time, so calling the metric object and passing the whole dataset is usually not an option. `update_state` aims at accumulating statistics for the metric and is called ***after each batch***  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric#update_state. On the other hand, `result` is called when you need to display the current value of the metric (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch#low-level_handling_of_metrics).

Comment: Then it doesn't calculate the accuracy of the last batch but the accumulated accuracy till that batch. Isn't it?